# What are the benefits of using enum-flags?

Tags: c#, enums, boolean, flags

I wonder what the benefits of using Enum-flags instead of boolean fields (besides a better performance and cleaner code)...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute

Comment: Isn't better performance and cleaner code good enough for most features?

Answer (score 1):

> Flags enumerations are used for masking bit fields and doing bitwise
>   comparisons. They are the correct design to use when multiple
>   enumeration values can be specified at the same time.

As metioned above it is nothing more than correct design, but i guess this is what matters the most.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good that if you use flags you won't need many boolean parameters on a method if you have to pass many values. The flags make it easier to overload the method, too.